# Excel VBA: find and replace with offset

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets, shown below

[image]

[image]

What I would like to do is, write a VBA subroutine that:
look for all instances of sheet 2 column A from sheet 1 column A,
then replace the corresponding sheet 1 column D with sheet 2 column B

Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Why does this need VBA?  Couldn't you just use  [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Comment: Apologies, I actually would like to link this to a button you click that will execute only on command. If you have a better solution, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may give this a try...

```
Sub CompareAndReplaceData()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim x, dict

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = ws1.Range("A2:A" & lr)

x = ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x(i, 2)
Next i

For Each Cell In Rng
    If dict.exists(Cell.Value) Then
        ws1.Cells(Cell.Row, "D") = dict.Item(Cell.Value)
    End If
Next Cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```